# Banner ads, clickTag and transferring variables in the query string - Is there a standard?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, banner, clicktag

Is there a standard way to send variables through a banner ad? A client wants a banner that lets the user enter his mobile number, then receives a code by sms, and then enters the code into the banner. If the code then validates, the user is sent to a page with a login form with the phone number and code filled in. It must be possible to add the phone number and code as parameters to the clickTag somehow?

I found that Adform supports using ";cppar=1&" and then variable=value pairs, but is this a standard, or a special feature of Adform?

I've been trying to find some technical information on the different ad serving solutions, but can't seem to find anything other than a lot of different ways to implement clickTag in AS3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each seperate company will have their own way of supporting this as the whole point of adform is to act as a portal to your click (so that it can track it properly) therefore each will have a seperate method of dealing with variables (some dont allow it at all). The "standard" is variable=value pairs, you just have to see what the "initialising" code is for them (eg. ";cppar=1&").

if you are going through a specific company, ask them what they use for variables, if not then decide which company first!